# Using MAX() as condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, max

Wanted to know if I could do this without the sub-query

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_name
WHERE id = 123456
AND attempts = (
    SELECT MAX(attempts)
    FROM tbl_name
    WHERE id = 123456
)
```

Wanting to do something like this

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_name
WHERE id = 123456
AND attempts = MAX(attempts)
```

I get this when I try:

```
ERROR:  aggregates not allowed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is no, you cannot mix aggregate and non aggregate values

Comment: Long answer is: for this case there is **no need** to use an aggregate value

Comment: @Phil if you find Andomar's answer is better please unmark my answer so I can delete it

Answer (score 4):

You can do that using windowing functions

```
select  *
from    tbl_name
WHERE   id = 123456
        and 1 = row_number() over (partition by id order by attempts desc)
```

Answer (score 1):

That is **not** possible because the conditions in the `WHERE` clause are applied to each row individually, whereas `MAX` refers to an aggregated value, i.e., an aggregation of data from one or more rows.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to achieve this with a group by statement:

```
SELECT A.ID, MAX(A.Attempts)
FROM Table_Name AS A
WHERE A.ID = 123456
GROUP BY A.ID
```

Or perhaps slightly different:

```
SELECT A.ID, MAX(A.Attempts)
FROM Table_Name AS A
GROUP BY A.ID
HAVING A.ID = 123456
```